# Upload into specific folder Firebase Storage NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Hey I have found out how to upload into the firebase storage:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: secret,
  databaseURL: secret,
  storageBucket: secret,
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();


const uploadToFireStorage = (filename, query, fileType, imageURL) => {
  bucket.upload(filename).then(console.log("uploaded"));
};
```

As you can see with my bucket.upload function I can upload to firebase storage but it gets uploaded into the root folder and I want to put it under /foodImages/myfile.png for example
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Google Cloud Storage does not have genuine "folders".

In the Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented in a hierarchical structure of folders (just like the file system on your local hard disk) but this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket. The Cloud Storage console just uses the different parts of the file paths to "simulate" a folder structure, by using the "/" delimiter character.

So, you need to use an [`UploadOptions`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#UploadOptions) object as shown in the [doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) with a `destination` property which is defined with some "/", as follows:

```
const destinationFilename = "folder1/myfile.png";
bucket.upload('...', { destination: destinationFilename });
```

Comment: This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) on Cloud Storage and gsutil explains and illustrates that there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket and this "illusion of a hierarchical file tree"

Answer (score -1):

From the official documentation:

> If you want to use a storage bucket other than the default provided above, or use multiple storage buckets in a single app, you can retrieve a reference to a custom bucket as shown below:

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("foodImages");
```

(Modified the code to use ES6's const and to fit your example)

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_custom_buckets

Just one thing, now that we use ES6, you can use `const` instead of `var`

Comment: Hello @swarajpure, the OP actually wants to upload under a "folder" in the **default** bucket. Your answer is correct for uploading to a different bucket or "custom bucket".